# Define ranges to cover gaps in a number sequence (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Simplifying my problem down - I have 6-digit field which assigns numbers to customers starting from 1 and ending to 999999. Most numbers are sequentially assigned, but numbers can be assigned manually by users, and this feature has been used in an unpredicatable pattern throughout the range.

We now need to identify numbers that have not been assigned (easy) - and then convert this into a number of ranges (seems complex).

For example given the following numbers have been assigned

```
1,2,3,4,5,
1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,
999101,999102,999103,999104,999105
```

I need a resulting set of ranges like

```
Start  End
6      1000
1006   999100
999106 999999
```

My thinking so far is this is probably too complex to write in queries - and best achieved by looping from 1 to 999999, and adding ranges to a temp table.

Interested to hear ideas as I can imagine there are a few approaches. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. This is a one-off exercise so even a non-SQL solution might be appropriate, if this were for example easily done in Excel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
declare @t table (num int)

insert @t values (2),(3),(6),(7),(9),(10),(11)

select 
    MIN(number) as rangestart,
    MAX(number) as rangeend
from
(
    select *,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by number) -
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by num,number) grp
    from 
    (   
        select number from master..spt_values where type='p' and number between 1 and 15 
    ) numbers 
    left join @t t
        on numbers.number = t.num       
) v
where num is null
group by grp
```

Reference : gaps and islands by itzik ben-gan

To create a numbers query upto 999999

```
select p1.number +  p2.number * 2048 as number
from 
(select * from master..spt_values where type='p' ) p1,
(select * from master..spt_values where type='p' and number<489) p2    
where p1.number +  p2.number * 2048 <=999999
```

Comment: Maximum consecutive stp_values.number is `2047` while it should be up to `999999`.

Comment: @gserg You can easily create a larger number table by self joining spt_values.

Comment: I would simply use `top(999999)` on a conditionless cartesian join of `spt_values`.

Comment: @GSerg then you'd have to define the sort, and you'd only get up to 999998 :)

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of `select top(999999) row_number() over(order by 0/0)` :)

Comment: master..spt_values will have only 1 to 2047. Will not work for this range

Comment: @Raj I was talking about selecting from a cartesian join which has `4190209` rows.

Comment: got it. I posted the comment witout refreshing. my bad

Comment: This works well and handles the leading and trailing ranges. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @t table (num int)

insert @t values 
(2),(3),(4),(5),
(1001),(1002),(1003),(1004),(1005),
(999101),(999102),(999103),(999104),(999105)

;with cte as
(
    select num,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY num)) + 1 as idx from @t
    union
    select 0 [num],1 [idx] --start boundary
    union
    select 1000000 [num],COUNT(num) + 2 [idx] from @t --end boundary
)
select c1.num + 1 [Start], c2.num - 1 [End] 
from cte c1
inner join cte c2 on c2.idx = c1.idx + 1
where c2.num != c1.num + 1
```

Comment: I like this approach more - but as-is doesn't handle the first and last ranges if the first and last digit are unused.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #temp (id int)

insert into #temp (id)
values (1),(2),(3),(1000),(1001),(1002),(2000)

--drop table #temp
with cte as
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by id) as rn
from #temp a 
)
select a.id + 1, b.id - 1
from cte a join cte b on a.rn = b.rn - 1 and a.id <> b.id -1
```

it wont include tail ranges, like 2001-9999

Comment: You'll need a semi-colon before your CTE declaration, otherwise you'll get a syntax error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.`

Answer (score 1):

Here is [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5dc19/30)

```
select 

case when max(n1)=0 then 1 else max(n1)end,
case when max(n2)=0 then 999999 else max(n2)end

from
(
select t.n+1 as n1,0 n2,
   row_number() over(order by t.n)
      +isnull((select 0 from t where n=1),1)  
      rn  
from t
left join t t2 on t.n+1=t2.n
where t2.n is null

union all 

select 0 n1, t.n-1 as n2 ,
row_number() over(order by t.n) rn 
from t
left join t t2 on t.n-1=t2.n
where t2.n is null
  and t.n>1
) t3
group by rn
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table(id int)
insert @t values
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(1001),(1002),(1003),(1004),(1005),
(999101),(999102),(999103),(999104),(999105)

select t1.id+1 [start], coalesce(t3.[end], 999999) [end] 
from @t t1
left join @t t2 on t1.id +1 = t2.id
cross apply
(select min(id)-1 [end] from @t where t1.id < id
) t3
where t2.id is null
```

Comment: This misses out the initial start range if the first entry is missing

Comment: I tried this and with my real data was still running after 4 minutes. Looks good though apart from that. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

if you have a table called "**kh**" for example with a column "**myval**" which is your list of integers you could try this SELECT.

```
SELECT MAX(t1.myval+1) AS 'StartRange',t3.myval-1 AS 'EndRange' 
FROM kh t1, kh t3
WHERE t1.myval+1 NOT IN (SELECT myval FROM kh t2 ORDER BY myval)
AND t3.myval-1 NOT IN (SELECT myval FROM kh t4 ORDER BY myval)
AND t1.myval < t3.myval
GROUP BY  t3.myval
ORDER BY StartRange
```

Comment: Errored with "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified."